# How to run a daemon forever using Akka Actor?

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, akka

- My project is **not** using `Akka` as of now, it runs as a single process and does too many things.
- As a first inital step, we are trying to put a scaffolding in place so that we get Fault Tolerance. For example,

> ```
> ProjectSupervisor
>      |
> ExistingProcessActor
> ```

Where `ExistingProcessActor` would run as a forever long running job anf if it gets killed because of some `Exception`, `ProjectSupervisor` will `restart` it

I wasn't too sure about this, so I asked on [user-group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/akka-user/_qV5b2zpx74/kBYYPiEdmo8J), and received an interesting advice as

> [Me]  def run: Unit = LogReaderDisruptor.main(Array())
>   is a method that is supposed to run forever, plus it required some setup (that is available on client's machine or test environment)
>
> [Advice here] By that do you
>   mean that the main() is never returning? If so, then you're blocking
>   the Actor and wasting an entire thread. Spawn this off on a dedicated
>   dispatcher instead (see dispatchers and futures docs).

I went through the documentation but did not understood what I need to do.

Does that mean following?

- ExistingProcessActor will start a new `future` by giving a custom dispatcher of type `PinnedDispatcher`?
- If so, then in case of any failure how would `ProjectSupervisor` be notified? He is monitoring `ExistingProcessActor` and not `future` (`future` is not `Actor`)

I am confused, kindly guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a Future in order to have the work done in a dedicated dispatcher. This can be done by spawning an actor and assigning that actor to the dedicated dispatcher. A simple example from the akka docs:

```
val myActor =
  context.actorOf(Props[MyActor].withDispatcher("my-dispatcher"), "myactor1")
```

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/dispatchers.html

You could do this within your project supervisor when creating the `ExistingProcessActor`, putting that actor on a pinned dispatcher, and then your supervision strategy will continue to work as you want.